# Dataset error in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS report which contains multiple data sets which executes stored procedures. The same report is running well in my DEV environment. But not in PROD. I am able to run all the data sets individually in SSRS designer. Also im able to execute the same stored procedures in SSMS. **When I run the whole report once, it is throwing the below error.**

> An error has occurred during report processing.(rsProcessingAborted)
>   Query execution failed for dataset 'ABC'.(rsExecutingCommand)
>   For more information about this error navigate to the rport server on the local server, or enable remote errors.

Comment: Check the authentication type and settings you are using to connect to the data source

Comment: Look in the error log on the ssrs server.   It will have the details about the error that occurred.

Comment: On my box (2008R2) the error logs are here:   ..\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles

Comment: Thanks. It is the problem with my Global data source. I recreated it. It works...